# HTML Input fields tabindex issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating HTML form using Bootstrap and I have a problem with input field indexes.

The fields are displayed side by side on Desktop (2 fields in a single row). Now when the tab is pressed the cursor goes to 2nd rows first field, which I don't want. So I fixed that issue by using `tabindex`

Another issue arises on mobile, as the input field are displayed one by one on mobile (1 field each row). When we press tab from first field it goes to third field, which looks very odd and I want to fix it...

Here are the live examples:

**Desktop:**

```css
.col-md-6{
width: 50%;
float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">

  <div class="form-group">
    <span>Field 1</span>
    <input type="text" id="field1" tabindex="1"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <span>Field 3</span>
    <input type="text" id="field3" tabindex="3"/>
  </div>
  
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">

  <div class="form-group">
    <span>Field 2</span>
    <input type="text" id="field2" tabindex="2"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <span>Field 4</span>
    <input type="text" id="field4" tabindex="4"/>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

**Mobile:**

```html
<div class="col-md-6">

  <div class="form-group">
    <span>Field 1</span>
    <input type="text" id="field1" tabindex="1"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <span>Field 3</span>
    <input type="text" id="field3" tabindex="3"/>
  </div>
  
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">

  <div class="form-group">
    <span>Field 2</span>
    <input type="text" id="field2" tabindex="2"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <span>Field 4</span>
    <input type="text" id="field4" tabindex="4"/>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: the question's title is odd

Comment: What has the title to do with your question?

Comment: I am sorry, I was about to ask that question. But stackoverflow system suggested that these type of questions are mostly unanswered and downvoted so I did not ask question. And forgot to update title. Really sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping your `cols` in `rows`
[codepen](https://codepen.io/fen1x/pen/WOPMOa)